# audio only works when booted with headphones plugged in

Tags: boot, 16.04, sound, headphones

I built my compute recently with ASUS Z270-A motherboard and installed ubuntu 16.04. Everything is splendid except audio.

When I boot my computer without headphones, audio simply won't work. When i plug in my headphones, ubuntu detects it but when i switch my headphones as output, it won't generate any audio.

HOWEVER, when I boot my computer with my headphones already plugged in, audio works perfectly. But if I unplug it and plug it back in, it doesn't work.

This is rather very odd. Does anyone know what the problem is?